# HTML Text positioning not aligning in center

Tags: html, css

i want to center the text but the second line dont wanna raise litle bit help?

```
 <div class="slog-log"  style="margin-bottom: 2px; ">
   <div class="row">

       <div class="col-md-3 " style="margin: 1px 0px 19px 15px ;width: 140px;height: 90px;">
           <img  src="images/logo.png" alt="" class="img img-responsive" ><!--style="margin:15px;"-->
       </div> 
       <div class="col-md-9" style="width: 992px;height: 90px;background-color: #777;margin: 9px 0px 0px 7px;">
           <i ><h3 style="margin-left: 30%;">Orum Lipsum Blaste</h3></i>
           <i ><h3 style="margin-left: 20%;">laba Raba Lokus Focus</h3></i>
      </div> 
    </div>     
  </div>
```

Comment: also the first line is not centered.

Comment: You should not be using inline CSS styles. Put your code in an external CSS file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first and the second line are not centered because of the `margin-left` applied to them.
Remove it and add a `text-align: center;`

```
<i><h3 style="margin-left: 30%; padding-top:15px;">Orum Lipsum Blaste</h3></i>
<i><h3 style="margin-left: 20%;">laba Raba Lokus Focus</h3></i>
```

http://jsbin.com/yegogefaqaxo/2/edit

Comment: the second h3 is in the botom of the div i want that h3 to raise litle bit can you tell me how ?

Comment: you want to reduce the distance between the two lines of text?

Comment: i wannte theme to be in the center of the dive and the same gap between the top be alsow in bottom plz :p

Comment: add some padding to the first `h3`, e.g.: `padding-top:15px`. See: http://jsbin.com/yegogefaqaxo/2/edit

Comment: thakns for help guys ^^

Answer (score 0):

Regarding centering the text, try it as simple as this one (adding text-align: center to the containing div):

```
<div class="col-md-9" style="width: 992px;height: 90px;background-color: #777;margin: 9px 0px 0px 7px; text-align:center">
       <i><h3>Orum Lipsum Blaste</h3></i>
       <i><h3>laba Raba Lokus Focus</h3></i>
  </div>
```